# Term by term integration

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^{d} $ be open. For $u,v \in C_{0}^{\infty}(D)$, we define
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{A}(u,v)=\sum_{i,j=1}^{d} \int_{D} \frac{\partial u(x) }{\partial x_{i}}\frac{\partial v(x) }{\partial x_{j}} \nu_{ij}(dx)
\end{eqnarray*}
Here $\nu_{i,j}\,(1\leq i, j \leq d)$ are Radon measures on $D$ ( they are not necessarily positive ) such that for any $\xi=(\xi_{1},...,\xi_{d}) \in \mathbb{R}^{d} $ and any compact set $K \subset D$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i,j=1}^{d} \xi_{i} \xi_{j} \nu_{ij}(K) \geq 0,\,\,\nu_{ij}(K)=\nu_{ji}(K),\,\,1\leq i, j \leq d
\end{eqnarray*}

I want to prove $\mathcal{A}(u,u) \geq 0 $ for all $u \in C_{0}^{\infty}(D)$.

Proof (unfinished)

Devide $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ into cubes with sides parallel to the axis and of side length $\delta >0$. Denote by $\{ C^{1},...,C^{l(\delta)} \}$ those cubes whose closures are contained in $D$. $l(\delta)$ depends on $\delta$ and values in $\{1,2,...\}\cup\{\infty\}$. Take a point $\eta^{(k)}$ from each cube $C^{k}$ and put $\frac{\partial u(\eta^{(k)}) }{\partial x_{i}}=\xi_{i}^{(k)}$.

Then for all $u \in C_{0}^{\infty}(D)$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{A}(u,u)&=& \sum_{i,j=1}^{d} \int_{D} \frac{\partial u(x) }{\partial x_{i}}\frac{\partial u(x) }{\partial x_{j}} \nu_{ij}(dx)\\
&=& \sum_{i,j=1}^{d} \left( \lim_{\delta \searrow 0}  \sum_{k=1}^{l(\delta)} \xi_{i}^{(k)} \xi_{j}^{(k)} \nu_{ij}(C^{k})  \right)\\
\end{eqnarray*}

I think if "$\lim_{\delta \searrow 0}  \sum_{k=1}^{l(\delta)} \sum_{i,j=1}^{d} \left| \xi_{i}^{(k)} \xi_{j}^{(k)} \nu_{ij}(C^{k}) \right|<\infty $" then we can interchange 
$\sum_{i,j=1}^{d}$ and $\lim_{\delta \searrow 0}\sum_{k=1}^{l(\delta)}$.

Since $u \in C^{\infty}_{0}(D)$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{\delta \searrow 0}  \sum_{k=1}^{l(\delta)} \left|  \sum_{i,j=1}^{d}  \xi_{i}^{(k)} \xi_{j}^{(k)} \nu_{ij}(C^{k}) \right|&=&\lim_{\delta \searrow 0}\sum_{k=1}^{l(\delta)} \sum_{i,j=1}^{d} \xi_{i}^{(k)} \xi_{j}^{(k)} \nu_{ij}(C^{k}) \quad {\rm(by\,assumption)} \\
&=&\int_{D} \sum_{i,j=1}^{d} \frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial x_{i}} \frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial x_{j}} \nu_{ij}(dx)< \infty \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Hence we can interchange $\sum_{i,j=1}^{d}$ and $\lim_{\delta \searrow 0}\sum_{k=1}^{l(\delta)}$. we get 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{A}(u,u)&=& \sum_{i,j=1}^{d} \int_{D} \frac{\partial u(x) }{\partial x_{i}}\frac{\partial u(x) }{\partial x_{j}} \nu_{ij}(dx)\\
&=& \sum_{i,j=1}^{d} \left( \lim_{\delta \searrow 0}  \sum_{k=1}^{l(\delta)} \xi_{i}^{(k)} \xi_{j}^{(k)} \nu_{ij}(C^{k})  \right)\\
&=& \lim_{\delta \searrow 0}   \sum_{k=1}^{l(\delta)} \left(  \sum_{i,j=1}^{d} \xi_{i}^{(k)} \xi_{j}^{(k)} \nu_{ij}(C^{k})  \right) \geq 0\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Is this proof correct? Can I get your opinion?

Comment: Need to replace one $u$ by $v$ in the integrand in the definition of $A(u,v)$.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking not an answer to your question but a solution that I think is essentially correct. Write $D$ as the union of an increasing sequence of compact sets $K_1\subset K_2\subset\cdots\subset K_n\subset\cdots$. Because of the property $\sum_{i,j=1}^d u_i(x)u_j(x)\nu_{ij}(K_n)\ge 0$ for each $x\in K_n$, $u_i(x)u_j(x)$ and $\nu_{ij}(K_n)$ have the same sign on $K_n$. The result now follows (via inner regularity) from the fact that $\sum_{i,j=1}^d\int_D u_i(x)u_j(x)\nu_{ij}(dx) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{K_n}\sum_{i,j=1}^du_i(x)u_j(x)\nu_{ij}(dx)$.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to understand you told.